# Angular UI Router View Disappearing

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, view, router

My site contains a LOT of script.

I have a view at the top of the page (topnav).  In the bottom half of the page is a view (main).  Clicking a link there activates a view on the right side (rightnav).  When I click a link in the rightnav, it changes the main view (as intended), but then rightnav disappears.

How can I keep that up while still changing the main view?

EDIT: updated with a Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/eba8t46pqGllufteLJlR

```
<h2>Apparently I have to have code to add a plunker</h2>
```

Comment: Please give more details how exactly your site looks. Try to remove everything that is unrelated, but such that the issue still persists.

Comment: Updated with a plunker, so you can see what I'm talking about.